# How to show content in react-horizontal-timeline?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
                        <HorizontalTimeline
                            index={this.state.value}
                            indexClick={(index) => {
                            this.setState({ value: index, previous: this.state.value });
                            }}
                            values={ VALUES.map(x => x.data) } 
                            getLabel={date=>VALUES.filter(x=>x.data==date).map((q)=> {return q.status})}
                            minEventPadding={50}
                            maxEventPadding={60}
                            linePadding={50}
                            isOpenBeginning={true}
                            isOpenEnding={false}
                            styles={{background: '#95cbdc', foreground: '#2791b3', outline: '#dfdfdf' }}
                            />
                        </div>
<div className='text-center'>
  {/* any arbitrary component can go here */}    
  {this.state.value}
</div>
```

what is that arbitrary component?? how to show different content based on index?

Comment: it doesn't give proper idea of your requirement, please explain or put reequired screenshot

Comment: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-timeline) this link has the details and demo @Vahid Akhtar